# How to store and show multiple related data fields Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have book and author model. I created Many2many field in Author model. when the name of the author is clicked, I want to show that the books of this Author. In my code,  I can see only the book which is last published. But I want to see every book. How can I do that?

### Author.py

```
_name = 'about.author'
_inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}

# Relation with Book
book_ids = fields.Many2many(
'about.book'
)

book_names = fields.Char('Books of The Author', related='book_ids.name',store=True,multi=True)
```

### Author.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
   <data>
      <!-- Views -->
      <record model="ir.ui.view" id="about_author_form_view">
         <field name="name">about.author.form</field>
         <field name="model">about.author</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
               <xpath expr="//field[@name='category_id']" position="after">
                  <field name="is_book_author" />
               </xpath>
            </data>
         </field>

      </record>
      <!-- Action -->
      <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="about_author_list_action" >
         <field name="name">Author</field>
         <field name="book_names" >Author Books</field>
         <field name="res_model">about.author</field>
         <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>

      </record>
      <!-- Menu -->
      <menuitem id="author_menu" name="Authors" parent="top_menu" action="about_author_list_action" />
   </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving `<field name="book_names" >Author Books</field>` to inside **view's record** tag from **action** solved the problem . Now,I can see all the books of the author.